# ionic 2 - css style of ion-datetime on open/close

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have `startDate` and `endDate` pickers in my ionic-2 app:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item class="eventCal-datePicker active">
            <ion-label>From</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime #startdatepicker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (ngModelChange)="startDateChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="startDate"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item class="eventCal-datePicker">
            <ion-label>To</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime #enddatepicker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (ngModelChange)="endDateChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="endDate"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I want to apply the following logic:

- When new date is assigned to startDate, the endDate is fired.
- Holder (`ion-item`) of active `ion-datetime` picker should have a proper `active` css class

I managed to open the other picker using this code:

```
startDateChange(val) {
  this.startDate = val;

  //check whether startDate > endDate and asssign later date in case it is

  //fire endDate picker
  setTimeout(() => this.endDatePicker.open(), 0);
}
```

What I **do not manage to do** is to change the css class of `ion-item` when the picker is fired and when it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the `ion-datetime` element has also `(click)` attribute:

```
<ion-datetime #enddatepicker (click)="setEndDatePickerClass()" ...
```

Inside `setEndDatePickerClass()` I call:

```
this.endDatePicker._isOpen
```

In order to determine the picker state, and:

```
this.endDatePicker._elementRef.nativeElement.className
```

in order to detgermine css class or assign a new one.

**Important!!**
Be aware to ticks delays. I am not sure in which order events are fired, but I had to do some acrobatics in order to make it work in all user cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-item [class]="yourDynamicClassName"
```

Assign class name to the variable `yourDynamicClassName` in .ts

Comment: Yes, but any idea how to bind it to ion-datetime open/close??